# lastRequestAt returning always 0.000000

Tags: ios7, quickblox

When sending a message I'm checking if opponent user is online / offline, so I can send him APNS if he's offline:

```
NSTimeInterval currentTimeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval userLastRequestAtTimeInterval  = [[self.opponent lastRequestAt] timeIntervalSince1970];
if((currentTimeInterval - userLastRequestAtTimeInterval) > 300)
{
  //SEND APNS
}
```

or

```
NSTimeInterval currentTimeInterval = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
if(currentTimeInterval - [self.opponent.lastRequestAt timeIntervalSince1970] > 300)
{
    //SEND APNS
}
```

Opponent user lastRequestAt is always returning 0.000000 so it's always sending APNS, even when opponent is online.

I can get my user.lastRequestAt after login with username and password.

What I'm getting "null" is the "opponent user" last request when sending him a message: opponent.lastRequestAt.

self.opponent is not null, I have it's ID but not lastRequestAt property:

```
[QBUUser]:  
    ID:859106   
    created at:(null)   
    updated at:(null)           
    externalUserID:0            
    blobID:0            
    facebookID:(null)           
    twitterID:(null)            
    full name:(null)            
    email:(null)            
    login:(null)            
    phone:(null)            
    tags:(null)            
    lastRequestAt:(null)            
    website:(null)
```

I'm just sending message to opponent using it's ID as reference:

```
QBChatMessage *message = [[QBChatMessage alloc] init];
message.recipientID = self.opponent.ID;
[[QBChat instance] sendMessage:message];
```

What I can read in Output panel about getting opponent is:

```
GET https://api.quickblox.com/users/859106.xml

headers:{
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 1.8.2";
    "Qb-Token" = 41243a780d6cb457e5fe88c4cf6e4827c6f88568;
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}
```

Should be necessary to get opponent QBUser data other way before sending him a message?

Comment: Add code for method `lastRequest`. Also check if self.opponent is null.

Comment: How did you retrieve opponent's user entity?

Comment: just sending him a message....see edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to send message you need only user ID. But if you want to use lastRequestAt field, you need to retrive QBUUser from Quickblox database. If you use [QBUUser user], you  will create new user locally. Quickblox doesn't know this user yet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any additional details?

I have just create new user in Admin panel, did login

```
  [QBUsers logInWithUserLogin:@"garrybons" password:@"garrybons"  delegate:self];
```

and log result:

```
2014-02-18 13:37:43.636 Snippets[66541:70b] QBUUserLogInResult, user=   
[QBUUser]:  
    ID:875661   
    created at:2014-02-18 11:31:00 +0000    
    updated at:2014-02-18 11:31:00 +0000            
    externalUserID:0            
    blobID:0            
    facebookID:(null)           
    twitterID:(null)            
    full name:(null)            
    email:(null)            
    login:garrybons         
    phone:(null)            
    tags:(null)            
    lastRequestAt:2014-02-18 11:31:24 +0000         
    website:(null), 
 socialProviderToken=(null), 
 socialProviderTokenExpiresAt=(null)
```

As you can see, lastRequestAt != null

Please provide additional details

Comment: Should be necessary to get opponent QBUser data other way before sending him a message?